# How to allow special characters such as * or ? in a token in Antlr

Tags: antlr4

I am specifying a token in my antlr grammar as:

```
ID : [a-zA-Z0-9\*\?];   // Allow tokens such as Asdf*fdsa
```

But I get an `invalid escape sequence \*` error. How can I specify special characters in the character set that Antlr allows for tokens?

Comment: @GRosenberg sorry, transcription error. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` and `?` don't have a special meaning inside character classes and don't need to be escaped. So just remove the backslashes and you're good.

You'll also want to add a `+` after the character class if you want to be able to match more than one character (as in the example).

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I didn't try that first.